# c# - Filtering .zip file out of FileInfo array

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, fileinfo

I have a FileInfo array, which returns me 15 files and one ".zip" folder. I basically need to try and somehow filter this ".zip" file out of the array. Any help would be much appreciated, but it seems I am just banging my head against a brick wall! Here is the code that I am trying to impliment this into;

```
public List<FileInfo> getInfo(bool recursive, int ageDays)
{
  //Declarations
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(CurrentFilePath);
  FileInfo[] fi = new FileInfo[0];
  List<FileInfo> results = new List<FileInfo>();
  fileResults = new List<Files>();
  DateTime ageInDays = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-ageDays);

  //Checks for recursive search
  if (recursive)
  {
    try
    {
      fi = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
  }
  else
  {
    try
    {
      fi = di.GetFiles();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
  {
    if (fi[i].LastWriteTime < ageInDays)
    {
      results.Add(fi[i]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
        {
            if (fi[i].LastWriteTime < ageInDays && fi[i].Extension != ".zip")
            {
                results.Add(fi[i]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I had no idea there was such thing as a ".Extension". Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Best to change your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
{
    if ((fi[i].LastWriteTime < ageInDays) && fi.Extension.ToUpper() != ".ZIP")
    {
        results.Add(fi[i]);
    }
}
```

Or use LINQ:

```
results = (from fi in results
           where fi.Extension.ToUpper() != ".ZIP"
           select fi).ToList<FileInfo>();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
      _files = Directory.GetFiles(FTPOutputDirectory);
       foreach (string fi in _files)
         {
           string fi = Path.GetExtension(f);

            if (fi.ToUpper() != ".ZIP" )
             {
                // yourWork
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lambda to check the extension of your file

```
var files = di.GetFiles().Where(file => !file.FullName.EndsWith(".zip"));
```